# Why can't I see event handlers in Inspect element of microsoft edge?

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to view the event handlers(under Elements section) I have attached them to my react projects on Microsoft edge when I inspect. Why is it so ?

Comment: can you add more detail? maybe a screenshot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.